# how does msg.exe work in terms of mailslot?

Tags: msg, mailslot

I am really trying to find out how msg.exe work in windows 10. does it even use mailslot or uses socket? if it uses mailslot then what is the slot name(for example net send uses "\*\mailslot\messngr"). if anyone could answer thanks in advance.

Comment: I think `msg.exe` is using IPC to connect to RDSH. The [mailslot mechanism itself is using IPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/mailslots) too.

Comment: I am kinda want to use the mailslot to send message using c++ from one computer to another on the network but it is not working in windows 10. is there a format for sending message like for example "to\0from\0message" and msg.exe works fine in windows 10.

Comment: You should put your code in the question, tag it with `C++` and you're way more likely to get a helpful answer

Comment: LPCSTR slotNameOfMSGexe = "\\\\*\\mailslot\\messngr"; is this the slot name which the msg.exe use?

Comment: You are missing one backslash, 4 slashes escape 2 slashes and also try with a `.` instead of `*` first: `LPCSTR slotNameOfMSGexe = "\\\\.\\mailslot\\messngr";`

Comment: thanking for pointing it out but what i REALLY wanted to know out here is, what slot name does msg.exe use? because the above definitely is not the one used by msg.exe in windows 10 pro (ie "\\\\.\\mailslot\\messngr" or "\\\\computername\\mailslot\\messngr").

Comment: My dear friend, I know nothing about this kind of windows wizardry but does [this link about listing all mailslots](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/712fb524-e3b7-49d4-a686-2e89c0efc5fa/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-open-mailslots-in-windows?forum=netfxbcl) help you to find out? I think there is a way to see the mailslot paths somehow.

Comment: thank you for the help. i am very grateful to you @DanielW.

Comment: still searching the www